# PHP 5.4.3 RPM and steps of installation?

Tags: installation, php, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

Can someone please point me a PHP 5.4.3 RPM that includes mysql and PDO ?

I appreciate if someone can guide me or give me link to step by step installation of rpm.

I have redhat linux.

(gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48))

Answer (score 2):

Use yum install php-mysql.x86_64